# determining default port for scheme

Tags: php, parse-url

Is there a php command to determine the default port for a given url? `parse_url` only seems to return the port if it is explicitly specified in the url, but my function needs to return the correct port regardless.

Examples:

```
parse_url('http://example.com:81') //returns port 81

parse_url('http://example.com') //doesn't have a port in the return, but I must return 80

parse_url('https://example.com') //doesn't have a port in the return, but I must return 443
```

I could certainly create a hardcoded mapping of schemes to ports, but is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think so - a hardcoded mapping looks like the only way. Given that the mapping is unlikely to change anytime soon, I'd say it's not that bad an option, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getservbyname does just that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getservbyname.php

Comment: Just a note: the "service" name and URI scheme do not necessarily have to correspond. For most common schemes, this will work fine, but for example [`prospero`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4157.html) gives you 191, while it should be 1525 (per the RFC), which is actually called `prospero-np` as a service.